# SQL Server 2005 Dividing two rows in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a table set up like this:

```
        Description                Jan |  Feb  | Mar  | Apr .....   
Volume        

Days in Month

Gal/Day Average
```

I would like to be able to divide the volume for each month by the Days (and multiply by 100) to fill in the gal/day average row for each month.

The farthest I've gotten code wise is:

```
Update Table
set [Jan] = ?
where Description = 'Gal/Day Average'
```

Answer (score 1):

Not a very good data format, but you could do:

```
Update toupdate
    set [Jan] = volume.jan / dim.jan
    from table toupdate cross join 
         table volume cross join
         table dim
    where toupdate.description = 'Gal/Day Average' and
          volume.description = 'Volume' and
          dim.description = 'Days In Month';
```

A much better data format would have the columns:

- month
- (possibly year)
- volume
- daysinmonth
- average

Comment: Query executes but doesn't seem to populate the cell with anything? (NULL).

Comment: Check that the strings for the descriptions are correct.  There is probably a mismatch in the `where` that results in the `from` returning no rows.

Comment: Double checked. Where are the "volume" and "dim" tables coming from in your code? I only have the one "toupdate" table.

Comment: @user3532047 . . . Those are table aliases.  I don't know what `toupdate` is.  Your question has only one table mentioned, called `table`, and that is what this query uses.

Comment: Shouldn't they be column aliases? If I use "table" in front of all 3 it gives me a syntax error. Removing "table" lets it executes but with NULL values.

Comment: @user3532047 . . . "table aliases" are names for tables defined in the `from` clause.  "column aliases" are names for columns defined in the `select`.  A column reference in other clauses -- such as `select`, `on`, `where`, `group by`, `having` -- can be qualified with a table alias.